# Loading Sentinel 2 images downloaded with QGIS in SNAP software?

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2, sentinel-snap

I have downloaded Sentinel 2 images using the semi-automatic classification plugin in QGIS, but I cannot open these files in SNAP software.

I can load .jp2 products in SNAP but I obtain a error when I try to open the XML file in SNAP.

> Error: `No appropriate product reader found`

My SNAP version is the 5.0 and the image identifier is: `S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_SGS__20161117T180146_A007341_T30TXN`

Comment: You need to provide more information. For example screenshots, error messages etc.

Comment: We need to know your SNAP version and the product version or ID of your Sentinel-2 scene. Most likely it is a newer scene and you are using an older SNAP version that needs to be updated.

Answer (score 3):

I would say SNAP does not read Sentinel-2 images as `.jp2` files. A specific format is used instead. Although SCP does a great job, the output does not contain all the metadata information.  I would recommend you to download the S-2 images directly from the Copernicus Open Acces Hub (https://scihub.copernicus.eu/). There, you can download your image as a zip folder. Then:

- Unzip the folder
- Open snap
- Click on the open product icon
- Navigate to your image unzip folder
- Select the .xml file

Depending on the date of your image, the `.xml` file will have the same name as the zip folder OR it will be named MTD_MSIL2A.xml

[image]